# Single Data frame to Multiple with condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, optimization, grouping

I need to create a dataframe in pandas to split the production output to customers based on the demand

Date      Model B1  Model B2
10/1/2022   100     120

10/2/2022   100     120

10/3/2022   80      110

10/4/2022   100     120

10/5/2022   100     120

10/6/2022   100     120

10/7/2022   100     120

10/8/2022   100     120

10/9/2022   100     120

10/10/2022  120     120

10/11/2022  120     120

10/12/2022  130     120

10/13/2022  110     120

10/14/2022  100     120

Customer demand as below

Requirement
Customer A (Gets Model B1)
Week    Qty
Week 1  300
Week 2  400

Customer B (Gets Model B1)
Week    Qty
Week 1  380
Week 2  380

Customer B (Gets Model B2)
Week    Qty
Week 1  830
Week 2  840

If i can fix/allot Customer A requirement then the remaining should be given to other customer for Model B1
For Model B2 it all goes to 1 customer
Also the daily production has to be converted to weekly view for customers

Comment: give us an example of your data in text format not screenshot, and the expected output in text format as well

Comment: Updated as text